# How to make centred list view in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to start my page something like this,

[image]

But this is what my list view looks like, I need to center it like the first one, how can I achieve that
[image]

this is my listview.builder widget

```
Flexible(flex: 2,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: 10,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return const RowShoppingtile();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

can anyone suggest me way to do this

Comment: did you try using Center widget ?

Comment: yes,center widget makes all the listview to center, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ScrollController` to scroll the `ListView` to a desired position. Make sure to call to scroll after build is finished.

```
class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ItemList({super.key});

  @override
  State<ItemList> createState() => _ItemListState();
}

class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  late ScrollController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = ScrollController();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _controller.jumpTo((_controller.position.maxScrollExtent +
              _controller.position.minScrollExtent) /
          2.0);
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.deepPurple.withAlpha(100),
      height: 250,
      child: ListView(
        controller: _controller,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: List.generate(7, (index) => const _ListItem()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> **NOTE:**

Above sample only works for odd number of ListView items. Otherwise you need to calculate the scroll position accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This will make the ListView scroll by one page at a time instead of scrolling through each item.

```
ListView(
  physics: PageScrollPhysics(), // set the physics property to PageScrollPhysics
  children: [
    //Add your list items here
  ],
);
```